# What's the correct way to dynamically resize matrices in Matlab's mex?

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I am trying to dynamically realloc some arrays in mex depending on dynamic size of input data.

```
   std::vector<mxArray*> arrays;
   size_t row_size = 1;

   for(size_t i = 0; i < col_count; ++i) {
     mxArray* output = mxCreateNumericMatrix(row_size, 1, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
     arrays.push_back(output);
   }

   void grow() {
     size_t new_size = row_size * 2;
     for(size_t i = 0; i < col_count; ++i)
       mxSetM(arrays[i], new_size);
     row_size = new_size;
   }

   size_t current_row = 0;
   while(...) {
     if(current_row >= row_size)
       grow();

     //do some assignment to the arrays
     double* p = mxGetPr(arrays[col]);
     p[current_row] = value;

     ++current_row;
   }
```

This works for awhile, but I am obviously corrupting memory somehow, as it bombs randomly with:

```
MATLAB: double free or corruption (out): 0x00007f9714314f50 ***
```

If I pre-allocate the "matrix" (`grow` is never called) everything runs without issue.

Comment: `mxSetM` does not allocate memory, the documentation says that clearly. You need to also `mxRealloc` and `mxSetPr` the new pointer when resizing.

Comment: I assume I need to memcpy the existing values then?

Comment: @Alex Yeah, I think you'll need to: (1) allocate new memory (2) copy doubles from existing array to the new memory (3) assign the new memory to the mxArray (4) free the old memory.

Comment: @Alex note that memcpy will work fine for a one dimensional array, but if there are multiple columns and you are increasing the number of rows, memcpy will not work, you'll have to go element by element with appropriate indexing (Because MATLAB uses column major layout).

Comment: @MatthewGunn I assume this means that mxSetM basically only sets some concept of dimensionality, similar to std::vector.size() vs std::vector.capacity()?

Comment: @MatthewGunn Thanks for the help, gonna give this a shot, will report back.

Comment: The steps listed by MatthewGunn will work, but it's a bit easier to use `mxRealloc`. You `mxRealloc` new size, existing elements will be copied automatically and old array freed if necessary. `mxSetPr` the new pointer to your array, and then `mxSetM` to set the new rows.

Comment: @Praetorian I wasn't familiar with mxRealloc. That's clearly what should be used here!

Comment: @Praetorian If he had more than 1 column though, I think he may have to use my original system? Using 0 indexing, the `i,j` element should be at `i + n_rows * j` index in the data array (in column major layout). If n_rows changes, the position of everything beyond the first column would have to change in the underlying data array. Or maybe you could do a realloc and some real slick copying working from the back so you didn't need a scratch space...?

Comment: @MatthewGunn `mxRealloc` should be usable in the general n-dimensional case also. You'd `mxRealloc` with a size that is product of all the new dimensions, and then `mxSetPr` and `mxSetDimensions` to update the `mxArray`. You do have to be careful about column-major indexing when filling in the empty locations in the new matrix.

Comment: @Praetorian  `mxSetPr(arrays[i], (double*)mxRealloc(arrays[i], new_row_count * sizeof(double)));
        mxSetM(arrays[i], new_row_count);` Still causes the issue.  Perhaps because it mismatches with the way I create the array initially?

Comment: You're passing an `mxArray*` to `mxRealloc` instead of a pointer to the real data array. Try `mxRealloc(mxGetPr(arrays[i]), new_row_count * sizeof(double))` instead

Comment: @Praetorian Works perfectly, I didn't understand the level of indirection between the real array and the mxArray. Thanks for your help mate!

Comment: @Praetorian Simple example: You have a 1 row, 3 col matrix whose data array is `[1, 2, 3]`. Imagine the goal is to grow to a 2 row, 3 col matrix (filling in other elements with zeros). Calling realloc to expand the array would get you `[1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0]` (as I understand realloc) BUT the you still need to do a bunch of copying to get into the appropriate [column major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) form of `[1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0]`. This is only an issue if the number of rows changes and the number of columns before hand is greater than 1.

Comment: @MatthewGunn Yes, good point, you will have to do a bunch of copying to get the data into the right format in that case